# Passing an object between many classes with the least coupling possible

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns

In my app I use a class (which is a singleton for now), called ClassA for the example, for managing stuff.

Because it's a singleton, I used this behavior to get this unique instance in many classes that needs it.

But now, i can't keep this class as a singleton anymore, I need to have one instance by NSDocument.

So I created an instance of the ClassA on my NSDocument subclass but the problem is for passing this object on classes that needs it.

I have this kind of structure :

Class1 <- Class2 <- Class3 <- Document -> ClassA

I need to have access of the instance of ClassA of Document in Class1.

I can use Dependency Injection to pass ClassA in Class1 by init or setter methods but because Document does not have direct access to Class1, I need to pass it to Class3 then Class2 then Class1.

Is this the only way to do that ? Or are there another better ways to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say go back to your singleton principle but use the `NSDocument` as the key into a dictionary of `ClassA` objects; something like:

```
static NSMutableDictionary *_classCache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

+ (ClassA *)classAForDocument:(NSDocument *)document
{
    ClassA *classA = [_classCache objectForKey:document];
    if (classA == nil)
    {
       // Initialise with something specific to the document I guess...
        classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
        [_classCache setObject:classA forKey:document];
    }
    return classA;
}
```

This then only requires that `Class{1,2,3}` know the document they belong to.

Comment: Yes but now the problem is how retrieve the current NSDocument in my Class1 ? I can't use [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] currentDocument] because it doesn't work in a drag operation and I need that. It is what I used before. And if I need to pass the document to my Class{1,2,3}, it's the same than passing directly the ClassA.

Comment: @Johnmph Yes, this was noted in my answer.  At the end of the day, those objects are going to have to know how they relate to the rest of the app if you want to use this type of approach rather than the cascading `initWith...` approach you mention in your question.

Comment: Thank you, so there is no magical way to do that without singleton or dependency injection ;)